# Chart select values from one column based on values in another column (Excel or SigmaPlot)

Tags: excel, charts

Does anyone know if it's possible to generate a chart  in Excel or SigmaPlot or select values in one column based on the value in another column without having to generate new columns to break out the data.

For example, using the data below I would like a continuous record of 'Date' on the x-axis.  On the y-axis I would like to plot all of the Q data. However, on a secondary axis I would only like to plot the 'T' values that correspond to a 'T-flag' = 1.  Again, if possible, I don't want to have to create any new columns because I have ~80 columns with different variables that I would like to create this type of plot for...

```
Date        Q    T    T-flag
01/01/1981  1.2  2.2  0
01/02/1981  1.3  2.1  0
01/03/1981  1.5  3.1  1
01/04/1981  1.2  2.1  0
01/05/1981  1.5  3.2  1
```